# Undefined index Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

In my blade template I have:

```
 {{ [ 'label' => 'Author:'  , 'custom'=> \Auth::User()->name ] }}
```

But when I want to use like this:

```
 ( null !== $options['custom']) ? $set = $options['custom'] : false;
```

I see the error **Undefined index: custom**? What is wrong?

Comment: How is your first line working in your blade template? It wants to echo an array?! It should give an error.

Comment: What are you trying to display. Post your controller. what is the 'custom' refers to..

Comment: Are you trying to make `$set = false` if `$options['custom']` isn't set?